# Word for "lacking synonymy"?

Tags: single-word-requests

Does a term exist for the class of words in English that have no exact synonyms (duodecimal, petrichor, labrador, to cite a few random examples)?  This would be that class of words for which a thesaurus could provide only a circumlocution.

Comment: The existence of such a class is highly questionable in the first place. To a first approximation, I don't think English actually *has* true complete synonyms.

Comment: The word for words that have no exact synonyms is ... 'word'. There are no exact synonyms, except maybe in domains with stipulated definitions like math and scientific/technical fields.

Comment: I think non-synonym or non-synonymous works

Comment: Simply "unique"?

Comment: So, Swadesh lists, or Swadesh 100, is known to Wictionary, Wikipedia, and Oxford Dictionary of Linguistics but not apparently to Merriam-Webster or Oxford on line. Thanks ermanem for the link. Another basic vocabulary list was developed for Ladybird Books.

Comment: Hehe: googlewhack.

Comment: @ermanen.  Excellent link.  That gives me some very good leads.  Cheers!